# Show Hidden dev from a cloned dev

Tags: javascript, html, clone

I was able to set up the cloning perfectly. But when I clone from one field to another, the hidden fields don't get trigged on the field I'm cloning to. Right now I have controller types being cloned. I set it up so you can choose clone car 1 car 2 etc. As you can see when you choose a controller type a picture pops up. But if a clone car 1 to car 2 the picture wont show up.

Heres my JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sr8360/rsF7w/

Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$('select[name="item_meta[2124]"]').change(function(){      

// ----------------------------- Clone from Car 1 (Car2) -----------------------------

if ($('select[name="item_meta[2124]"]').val()=="Car 1") {


// ---- Controller Type
var val1 = $("select[name='item_meta[9]']").val();                  
if (val1 !=undefined)
{$("select[name='item_meta[385]']").val(val1);}                     

}   // End Clone from Car 1    


// ----------------------------- Clone From Car 3 (Car2) -----------------------------

else if ($('select[name="item_meta[2124]"]').val()=="Car 3") {

// ---- Controller Type
var val2 = $("select[name='item_meta[386]']").val();                
if (val2 !=undefined)
{$("select[name='item_meta[385]']").val(val2);}    

}   // End Clone from Car 3 

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
});  // End of Car 2 Clone Drop Down ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


}); // End Entire Function
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your JSFiddle, but when I changed the "Clone" Select it came up with a JS error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: f2h3rt is not defined `. Maybe you should be investigated that instead of the function above.

Comment: Under Car 1 did you select something for controller type? then Under car 2 clone just select car 1. It works for my I tried it again right now.

Comment: Both clone car 1 and car 2 work for me right now.

Comment: Ok, I see. When I select a controller first, something happens. But that error keeps popping up in console. Can you maybe elaborate what you mean by *"the hidden fields don't get trigged on the field I'm cloning to"* in your question please.

Comment: That's weird. Anyway, so like when you choose Controller Type on car1. Do you see a picture pop up above it if you select AC Traction or Hydraulic? Will I have a few hidden Divs that I only want to show according to which controller type is chosen. It works perfect if I choose a controller type manually from a drop down. But lets say I want to clone Car 1's Controller Type into Car 2, I can clone it and it shows it in Car 2s drop down. But it's not registering because the DIVs that are triggered by Car 2s controller type selection aren't popping up when cloned.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out myself guys...

on:

I needed to add .change() to the end of each Var

so

```
var val1 = $("select[name='item_meta[9]']").val();                  
if (val1 !=undefined)
{$("select[name='item_meta[385]']").val(val1)**.change()**;}
```